Einfluss der altgriechischen Sprache auf Deutsch
Als griechischer Muttersprachler, der auch Altgriechisch studiert hat, konnte ich nicht umhin, die grammatikalischen Ähnlichkeiten mit Deutsch zu bemerken. Die Kasus sind nämlich dieselben (das muss ja kein Zufall sein) und viele Wörter wurden übernommen. Plus die Wörter, die durch Latein kamen, die Neologismen und so weiter.
Ich hatte jedoch Schwierigkeiten, Bücher oder andere Quellen zu finden, die über diesen Einfluss sprechen. Kennen Sie solche Quellen? (Auf Deutsch, Englisch oder Griechisch)

Die Ähnlichkeiten in der Grammatik haben ihre Ursache nicht in einer direkten Beerinflussung, sondern darin, dass sowohl Deutsch als auch Altgriechisch zu den indogermanischen Sprachen gehören.

Als österreichischer Muttersprachler, der Altgriechisch in der Schule gelernt hat, verstehe ich was du meinst; aber das ist, wie RHa richtig bemerkt, einfach ein historischer Confounder. Eine Kombination aus genetischer Verwandtschaft und Arealtypologie.

Ich erinnere mich, dass ich vor einiger Zeit irgendwo etwas über eine Verbindung zwischen beiden gelesen habe, insbesondere zwischen den Kasus, aber ich kann es nicht mehr finden. Haben Sie irgendwelche Buchempfehlungen, die dieses Thema näher beleuchten? Die indoeuropäischen Bücher, die ich gelesen habe, gehen nicht genug ins Detail.

Direkte Einflüsse des Griechischen auf das Deutsche sind mir nicht bekannt und ich würde sie, insbesondere was das Kasussystem betrifft, sogar ausschließen.
Sowohl Griechisch als auch Deutsch sind indogermanische Sprachen, so dass Ähnlichkeiten nicht überraschend, sondern sogar zu erwarten sind. (Deutscher Begriff: indogermanisch, englischer Begriff: indoeuropean. Beide Begriffe bedeuten dasselbe.)
Bei Wikimedia gibt es dieses Bild, das einen hypothetischen Stammbaum der indogermanischen Sprachen zeigt: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/4f/IndoEuropeanTree.svg
Das moderne Griechisch und sein Vorläufer Koiné, die gebräuchlichste Form des Altgriechischen, gehören zum hellenischen Zweig der indogermanischen Sprachen. Die einzige andere noch lebende hellenische Sprache ist nach diesem Stammbaum Tsakonisch (alternative Schreibweise: Zakonisch), dessen Vorläufer nicht Koiné, sondern Dorisch ist. Das moderne Standarddeutsch gehört dagegen zum westgermanischen Zweig, zu dem unter anderem auch Bairisch, Friesisch, Jiddisch, Niederländisch und Niederdeutsch gehören. Aber auch Englisch ist eine westgermanische Sprache.
Das moderne Deutsch ist aus einer Mischung mehrerer germanischer Sprachen/Dialekte entstanden, die von Völkern gesprochen wurden, die während der Völkerwanderung (ca. 4. bis 7. Jahrhundert) durch Europa zogen. Die althochdeutsche Sprache entstand aus einer Mischung der Sprachen Langobardisch, Altbairisch, Altalemannisch und Altfränkisch. Später kam noch Altsächsisch hinzu. Aus diesem Sprachengemisch entstand nicht nur Deutsch sondern auch Englisch.
Diese Sprachen der Völkerwanderungszeit gehören zu den germanischen Sprachen. Daneben gab es in dieser Zeit auch keltische und italische Sprachen, die zusammen mit den germanischen Sprachen zum westlichen Zweig der indoeuropäischen Sprachen gezählt werden. (Gelegentlich werden auch die baltischen Sprachen zu den westlichen indoeuropäischen Sprachen gezählt).
Griechisch gehört nicht zur westlichen Gruppe der indoeuropäischen Sprachen, sondern gemeinsam mit Armenisch und Phrygisch zu den Balkan-Indoeuropäischen Sprachen.
Die hypothetische Vorläufersprache aller genannten Sprachen ist die indogermanische Ursprache, die man auch Proto-Indoeuropäisch nennt. Von dieser Sprache gibt es keine direkten Belege, weil sie vor der Erfindung der Schrift gesprochen wurde. Sie ist eine von Wissenschaftlern in mühsamer Kleinarbeit rekonstruierte Sprache und spiegelt den besten Kompromiss aller Annahmen über diese Vorgängersprache wieder. Ihr werden acht verschiedene grammatische Fälle zugeschrieben:

Nominativ für das Subjekt des Satzes und für dem Subjekt gleichgesetzte Teile des Prädikats (Gleichsetzungsnominativ)
Vokativ für die Adressierung bzw. Anrede einer Person (selten auch einer Sache)
Akkusativ für das Ziel einer Bewegung und für direkt betroffene Mitwirkende der Handlung
Instrumental für Mittel und Werkzeuge
Dativ für indirekt betroffene Mitwirkende der Handlung, z.B. Nutznießer oder Geschädigte
Ablativ für den Ausgangsort der Bewegung und für die Ursache einer Handlung
Genitiv für die Abstammung oder Zugehörigkeit einer Sache oder Person
Lokativ für den Ort eines Gegenstandes und für Zeitangaben

Im Deutschen sind nur Nominativ, Akkusativ, Dativ und Genitiv als grammatische Fälle erhalten. Der Vokativ ist zu einer Stilfigur geworden (»Sehr geehrte Damen und Herren«, »O Tannenbaum«), der Instrumentalis existiert als Präpositionalobjekt (»mit dem Hammer«, »kraft seines Amtes«), ebenso der Ablativ (»von links«, »aus Osten«) und der Lokativ (»im Haus«, »unter der Brücke«).
Im Neugriechischen gibt es dagegen Nominativ, Akkusativ, Genitiv und Vokativ. Im Unterschied zum Deutschen gibt es im Neugriechischen den Dativ nur noch in wenigen festen Wendungen (εν τω μεταξύ = in der Zwischenzeit), und der Vokativ fällt fast immer mit dem Nominativ zusammen, weshalb er manchmal gar nicht als eigener Kasus gezählt wird. Nur Maskulina, die auf -ος enden (z.B. φίλος = der Freund), haben im Vokativ eine andere Endung (φίλε = O Freund, ...).
Bairisch (meine eigentliche Muttersprache) ist sehr nah mit dem Deutschen verwandt, hat aber nur zwei Fälle, nämlich einen Nominativ, der nur für das Subjekt und den Gleichsetzungsnominativ verwendet wird, und einen Obliquus, der als Verschmelzung von Dativ und Akkusativ aufgefasst werden kann und der für alles außer dem Subjekt verwendet wird. Im Bairischen gibt es keinen Genitiv. (Im Bairischen heißt es nicht: »das Auto des Bruders«, sondern »dem Bruder sein Auto«).
Englisch hat für Pronomen drei Kasus: Subjektiv (I, you, he, she, it), Possessiv (my, your, his, her, its) und Objektiv (me, you, him, her, it). Bei Substantiven fallen Subjektiv und Objektiv zu einem Obliquus zusammen (»The house is old.« »I see the house.«), nur der Possessiv wird markiert (»The house's roof is new.«)
Obwohl Englisch und erst recht Bairisch viel näher mit Deutsch verwandt sind als Griechisch, unterscheidet sich das deutsche Kasussystem stärker von den Systemen dieser beiden Geschwister-Sprachen als vom Griechischen.
Wenn die Ähnlichkeit der Kasussysteme von Deutsch und Griechisch auf einen direkten Einfluss des Altgriechischen auf die Vorläufersprachen der deutschen Sprache zurückzuführen wären, müssten auch Bairisch und Englisch denselben Einfluss erkennen lassen. Da aber zur Zeit der angenommenen Beeinflussung (vor der Völkerwanderung) die Vorläufersprachen von Bairisch, Deutsch und Englisch dasselbe Sprachengemisch waren, ist das auszuschließen.
Dass alle genannten Sprachen mehr oder weniger ähnliche grammatische Fälle verwenden, liegt daran, dass sich Deutsch und Griechisch sowie die anderen genannten Sprachen aus einem noch älteren gemeinsamen Sprachengemisch entwickelt haben, das man heute PIE (Proto-Indo-Europäisch) oder indogermanische Ursprache nennt.
Dass es unter den vielen Nachfolgesprachen von PIE ähnliche Konstellationen von grammatischen Fällen gibt, ist reiner Zufall. Das ergibt sich zwangsweise, wenn so viele Sprachen aus einer gemeinsamen Quelle entspringen.
Hier sind Beispiele weiterer zufälliger Ähnlichkeiten:
Meinen Recherchen zufolge verwenden Isländisch und Färöisch genau dieselben vier Fälle wie Deutsch, obwohl sie weniger eng mit Deutsch verwandt sind als z.B. Bairisch, das nur zwei Fälle hat.
Dieselben Fälle wie in Neugriechisch findet man im irischen Gälisch und im schottischen Gälisch. Das sind keltische Sprachen, die zwar auch indogermanische Sprachen sind, die aber kaum im Verdacht stehen, mit Griechisch verwandt zu sein.

Vielen Dank für die ausführliche Antwort. Ich habe etwas gefunden, das dem ähnelt, wonach ich gesucht habe, wenn Sie das Zitieren eines Youtube-Shorts entschuldigen können (es ist auch auf Griechisch) https://youtube.com/shorts/jwUFLlEzL9Q?si=QkKuMLuhk_UelvUC Es geht also um die modernere Entscheidung des Erfinders des gotischen Alphabets, die gotische Sprache auf etwas aufzubauen, das dem Griechischen näher steht. Obwohl ich verstehe, dass dies etwas ist, das später kam. Vielleicht ist das auch nur etwas, was die Griechen gesagt haben, um zu prahlen.

Es gibt eine gotische Bibel aus dem 4. Jahrhundert, die von Bischof Wulfila (311–383) geschrieben wurde. Die Goten benutzten bis dahin germanische Runen für Inschriften. Wulfila lehnte die heidnischen Runen ab und erfand für seine Bibel neue Schriftzeichen. Bei der Übersetzung versuchte er aber nicht, eine Übersetzung des griechischen Textes in jener Sprache herzustellen, die von den Goten gesprochen wurde, jedenfalls nicht so, wie man sich üblicherweise eine Übersetzung vorstellt. Stattdessen behielt er die griechische Grammatik weitgehend bei, und "übersetzte" einzelne ...

... Wörter. Die Wörter in der Wulfila-Bibel sind daher Gotisch, die Grammatik ist aber altgriechisch. Inwiefern die Wulfilia-Bibel die Gotische Sprache beeinflusst hast, weiß ich nicht. Ich weiß aber, dass Gotisch keine Westgermanische Sprache ist, sondern eine Ostgermanische. Und alle ostgermanischen Sprachen sind ausgestorben. Die meisten Sprachforscher gehen davon aus, dass die Sprache der Wulfilia-Bibel stark von der Sprache der Goten abwich. Falls Gotisch (und andere ostgermanische Sprachen) Westgermanische Sprachen beeinflusst hat, waren diese Einflüsse nur sehr schwach.
